# MultiLine text in CListCtrl cell appearing with ellipsis

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a`CListCtrl`, having a `Grid layout`, i.e., with rows and columns. I wish to display `multiline` text in the grid cells, but they get truncated and do not display in full, i.e., they display with ellipsis.

I have set a limit of the cell as 32. If the`CString` text to be inserted is more than half that, I insert a newline and carriage return into the `CString` at the halfway.

Unfortunately this causes the truncation of both lines with a `...`

How do i ensure that the string on the top is not truncated and continues properly from the second line, where, if more than 32, it can get truncated with a `...`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have a multi-line item in a ListControl MFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758085/how-can-i-have-a-multi-line-item-in-a-listcontrol-mfc)

Comment: Ah in my grid cell, I am getting a dual line text, as I require, but both get truncated with a `...`. For example, if the string is 'ThisStringHasThirtyTwoCharactersAndOneMore`, then the text getting displayed in my grid cell is, Top Line - `ThisStringHas...`, Bottom Line - `rtyTwoCharacte...`. Whereas I'd like it to be,`ThisStringHasThi` and `rtyTwoCharacte...`.

Comment: `CListCtrl` does not support multi-line items. You have to use a custom control. I don't know which custom control you are using. Give more details including `DrawItem` function of your custom control.